# Conflict with TAB keybinding for Yasnippet and Orgmode heading

Tags: org-mode, yasnippet

I tried to use Yasnippet to create a template for [org-drill](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-drill.html) "flashcard"

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: Orgdrill twosided card
# key: drill2
# --
* ${1:Write title here}                                                                                     :drill:
:PROPERTIES:
:DRILL_CARD_TYPE: twosided
:END:

${2:Write instructions here}

** ${3:Side Title : ex "German side"}
${4:Content of the card}

** ${5:Side Title : ex "French side"}
${6:Content of the card}

** Example/Hint (if any)
$0
```

Nevertheless, when added to the buffer I cannot go from field to field with the `TAB` key because it messes up with the behavior of the orgmode headings.

I tried to remap like this :

```
(define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "<C-prior>") 'yas-prev-field)
(define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "<C-next>") 'yas-next-field)
```

But I had no success

Comment: See if [this](https://orgmode.org/manual/Conflicts.html#Conflicts) helps.

Comment: Thanks, actually :
- I can go from field to field 
- I can edit all fields :
   - EXCEPT the first title
   - if I do not use any other key the AlphaNumeric Keys.
   - I cannot go backwards
It is enough. Thanks